# Java Timer fires out of band

Tags: java, timer, osgi, timertask

I created a Java class that checks every minute whether some heartbeat signal has arrived though some queue. While this so far has worked well a strange case was reported from production where there is an entry in the log every ms or even twice in a ms. This went on for about 40 min, till the admin detected the problem and restarted the application. Therafter, the heartbeat queue was ckecked again every minute according to the log which is the expected behavior.

The problematic log entries looks (simplified) like this:

```
16-03-2021 01:20:20.098 HEARTBEAT_NOT_OK. No initial heartbeat from server after application startup at 01.01.1970-00:01:09.444 for 18702 day(s) 01:19:10 (days hh:mm:ss). Heartbeat interval 60000 ms.
16-03-2021 01:20:20.099 HEARTBEAT_NOT_OK. No initial heartbeat from server after application startup at 01.01.1970-00:01:09.444 for 18702 day(s) 01:19:10 (days hh:mm:ss). Heartbeat interval 60000 ms.
16-03-2021 01:20:20.099 HEARTBEAT_NOT_OK. No initial heartbeat from server after application startup at 01.01.1970-00:01:09.444 for 18702 day(s) 01:19:10 (days hh:mm:ss). Heartbeat interval 60000 ms.
16-03-2021 01:20:20.100 HEARTBEAT_NOT_OK. No initial heartbeat from server after application startup at 01.01.1970-00:01:09.444 for 18702 day(s) 01:19:10 (days hh:mm:ss). Heartbeat interval 60000 ms.
```

The log text is always the same, for which I cannot find an explanation. Here is the simplified code of that Java class that should ckeck the hearbeat queue every minute:

```
@Slf4j
@Component(service = ServiceProvider.class)
public class HeartbeatReceiver implements ServiceProvider {

private static DateFormat DateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss.SSS");
private static long DefaultHeartbeatPeriodInMillis = 60_000;

private Timer timer;
private ReceivedHeartbeat lastHeartbeat = null;
private long heartbeatPeriod = DefaultHeartbeatPeriodInMillis;
private Object heartbeatPeriodLock = new Object();
private volatile long watchdogStartTime;
private Object heartbeatAliveLock = new Object();


@Activate
public void activate() {
    startWatchdog();
}

private void startWatchdog() {
    watchdogStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    startWatchdogTimer();
}

private void startWatchdogTimer() {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            checkHeartbeat();
        }
    }, delayTillFullMinute(), getHeartbeatPeriod());
}

private long delayTillFullMinute() {
    return 0; // omitted for brevity
}

public long getHeartbeatPeriod() {
    synchronized (heartbeatPeriodLock) {
        return heartbeatPeriod;
    }
}

private void checkHeartbeat() {
    synchronized (heartbeatAliveLock) {
        if (lastHeartbeat == null) { // just started up
            long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - watchdogStartTime;
            if(duration >= heartbeatPeriod) {
                logNoInitialHeartbeatReceivedAfterStartup(duration);
            }
            // omitted for brevity
            return;
        }

        // omitted for brevity
    }
}

private void logNoInitialHeartbeatReceivedAfterStartup(long duration) {
    log.error("HEARTBEAT_NOT_OK. No initial heartbeat from server after application startup at {} for {}. Heartbeat interval {} ms.",
        DateFormatter.format(watchdogStartTime), parseTime(duration), heartbeatPeriod);
}

public static String parseTime(long time) {
    return "foo"; // omitted for brevity
}

// other code omitted for brevity
```

}

My guess is that the OSGi @Activate annotation causes some class initialization problem, because of which var heartbeatPeriod is not initialized correctly. But then the log output should show the date 01.01.1970-00:00:00.000 and not 01.01.1970-00:01:09.444. This strange date 01.01.1970-00:01:09.444 also puzzles me.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a Timer task but you never cancel it on a deactivate. (Nor close the Timer itself, which will keep occupying a thread.)

So are you sure that this is not an old Timer running?

Comment: Thanks Peter, this is a good point. Our application is shut down by just killing the OS process it runs in. This is not how it should be. But the result is that all deactivate methods are never called. Nevertheless, you are rising a point that gives me new ideas what the bug could be :-).

Comment: A nasty problem in OSGi is 'jojoing'. At startup components get created/deleted because they start on default configuration and are then configured by Config Admin, or they get started by Config Admin and then the Configurator provides new config. Anyway, components should _always_ be properly cleaning up.

Comment: Please report back if this was related to the problem.

Comment: Didn't know about this "jojoing". Lucky you are when you get an answer from an OSGi expert :-). I will try this out. As it only occured once and never since it might be hard to recreate and then be sure that it is fixed. But I will make a fix that takes your point into account and augment the log to be able to see whether "jojoing" happened.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but you are synchronizing on

```
private Object heartbeatAliveLock = new Object();
```

Why not synchronize on

```
private HeartbeatReceiver heartbeatAliveLock  = null;
.
.
.
public HeartbeatReceiver()
{
   super();

   heartbeatAliveLock = this;
}
```

Comment: Hello Big Guy. Synchronizing over the this pointer would mean that any other synchronized block in the code would be closed for some other thread to enter it. With synchronizing over specific lock objects you have more fine grained control preventing a thread being in the this synchrionzed block locking out all other threads that want to enter some synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

`01.01.1970` is the epoch time. That is, `0L`. If you are really interested in elapsed time, then I would suggest using `System.nanoTime` instead which is much safer for elapsed time calculations. `System.currentTimeMillis` is for knowing the system time which can be changed while you are running.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will make use of this. However, the admin reported that he didn't change the system time. So the question how the timer could run out of band still remains.